PHP script doesn't rename file in docker container
I'm experiencing an issue with a Docker container running on a server. I have a PHP script that creates a CSV file (e.g., test_visit_events_unfinished.csv) when a user first visits the website. This file logs data related to an experiment on the site. Once the user completes the experiment, a JavaScript function sends a POST request to my PHP script in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. At this point, the PHP script should rename the file to test_visit_events_finished.csv.
What I want:
Once a new CSV file is created, it is named in the format test_visit_events_unfinished.csv. If the action finish is triggered, the file should be renamed to test_visit_events_finished.csv without modifying its contents.
What I tried:
I’ve tried multiple times to check if the file exists before renaming it, but no errors are thrown, and instead, a new file is created. I’ve verified the directory’s write permissions, and I suspect that the issue might be due to the user lacking permissions on this specific file. How can I dynamically assign the necessary permissions to the file?
Code
my php logic, the path to the file is correct. So the append and innit actions do work:
The file directory is defined as:
define('LOGDIR', '/var/www/html/logs');
define('LOGEXT', ".csv");

// Check if 'action' key exists in POST data
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === "init") {
    // Get name of log file, and ensure it's named with _unfinished by default
    $fid = $_POST['task'] ?? 'default_task'; // Default task if 'task' is missing
    $unfinishedFileName = $fid . "_unfinished" . LOGEXT; // Append _unfinished to the filename

    // Save data for the first time
    $header = "cursor,timestamp,xpos,ypos,event,xpath,attrs,extras" . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents(LOGDIR . "/" . $unfinishedFileName, $header . $info_data);
    
    // Notify recording script
    echo round(microtime(true) * 1000);

} else if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === "append") {
    // Get the log file name, use _unfinished if not specified
    $fid = $_POST['task'] ?? 'default_task'; // Default task if 'task' is missing
    $unfinishedFileName = $fid . "_unfinished" . LOGEXT; // Append _unfinished to the filename

    // Don't write blank lines
    if (trim($info_data)) {
        file_put_contents(LOGDIR . "/" . $unfinishedFileName, $info_data, FILE_APPEND);
    }

} else if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === "finish") {
    // Get the log file name without the suffix
    $fid = $_POST['taskname'] ?? 'default_task'; // Default task if 'taskname' is missing
    $unfinishedFileName = $fid . "_unfinished" . LOGEXT; // File with _unfinished suffix
    $finishedFileName = $fid . "_finished" . LOGEXT; // File with _finished suffix

    $originalFilePath = LOGDIR . "/" . $unfinishedFileName;
    $finishedFilePath = LOGDIR . "/" . $finishedFileName;

    if (file_exists($originalFilePath)) {
        // Check if the _finished file already exists to avoid overwriting
        if (!file_exists($finishedFilePath)) {
            // Rename the file to mark it as finished
            if (!rename($originalFilePath, $finishedFilePath)) {
                exit('Failed to mark file as finished');
            }
            echo 'File marked as finished';
        } else {
            exit('A file with _finished already exists');
        }
    } else {
        exit('Original _unfinished file not found');
    }
}

So the "renamed" file is still in the correct directory but didn't renamed the old file just created a new one.
here is my docker logic for giving the rights to write in the directory with contains the file:
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && \
    groupmod -g 1000 www-data && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html && \
    chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/logs

here is the javascript functions which should send the filename for changing the name:
async function finishExperiment(eventFile) {
    console.log("Now savint to: ", eventFile);
    // Send a request to the server to mark the log file as "finished"
    try {
        const response = await fetch("static/php/writeEvents.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  // Set content type to 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                action: "finish",         // The action type to perform
                taskname: eventFile       // The filename to mark as finished
            })
        });

        // Handle the response
        const data = await response.text();  // Assuming the server sends a plain text message
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error finishing the experiment:", error);
    }


What makes you believe it's a permission problem? If I correctly understand, the process creates a new files. On most systems, the permissions for renaming and creating are the same.

I don't believe it I thought about that because I don't have any idea why it's creating a new file instead renaming the old.

When you run the container, do you have any volume mappings?

Have you tried any debugging?

the volumes I mapped are the following: - ./app/logs:/var/www/html/logs -> this mapes my logs to a directory so the logs file can access out of the container. And I mounted the application files as volumes

it tells me in this line : if (!rename($originalFilePath, $finishedFilePath)) {
exit('Failed to mark file as finished');
}
echo 'File marked as finished'; that all was a success so it renamed the file

The issue was that the append action was called on one point after the finish action, which led to the creation of a new file with the _unfinished suffix, even though the file had already been marked as 'finished'.
